# Android marker and OSM mapview messed up when installing the app in different resolution

Tags: android-mapview, openstreetmap, screen-resolution, osmdroid

I am using a 1280 x 760 resolution phone. recently i tried to open my app that has open street map implemented in a 2560 x 1440 resolution phone. Little do i know, it actually messed up all my marker that i have plotted.

From what i understand when working with map, this shouldn't happen as i plot the marker using the lat long. (i set my zoom level to 18 (max))

Have anyone experiences this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar behavior on x86 machines where the dpi setting wasn't correct for the screen resolution. This causes misalignment of icons, polylines and more. The solution is simple, use the correct dpi settings for your device/display and don't change it while an osmdroid based application is running (or restart the app after it's been changed). Using a dpi and/or resolution that doesn't match with the actual number of pixels will cause alignment problems. (at least as of osmdroid 4.3)

Comment: Hi, i have tried adjusting the dpi, but it doesn't seems to help. is there any other way? or i guess i have to plot the marker again and again for different resolution(?)

Comment: It's also possible to add marker offsets. Is it possible that your marker's 'hotspot' is actually the problem?